# Where is pcl/io/openni_grabber.h?

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I compile PCL with ROS fuerte.

It says pcl/io/openni_grabber.h No such file or directory.

Here is my code:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
 #include <pcl/point_types.h>
 #include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
 #include <pcl/point_types.h>
 #include <pcl/io/openni_grabber.h>
 #include <pcl/common/time.h>
 #include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>
 #include <pcl/registration/icp.h>
 int
   main (int argc, char** argv)
 {
 
         pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new      pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
     pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer("Cloud Viewer");
         cloud->width=500;
         cloud->height=1;
         cloud->resize(cloud->height*cloud->width);
         for(int i=0;i<500;i++)
         {
                 cloud->points[i].x=i;
                 cloud->points[i].y=i;
                 cloud->points[i].z=i;
         }
 
            if (!viewer.wasStopped())
          viewer.showCloud (cloud);
            getchar();
   return (0);
 }
```

My Manifest:

```
 <package>
   <description brief="pcd_write">
 
      pcd_write
 
   </description>
   <author>sam</author>
   <license>BSD</license>
   <review status="unreviewed" notes=""/>
   <url>http://ros.org/wiki/pcd_write</url>
   <depend package="roscpp"/>
   <depend package="pcl"/>
   <depend package="pcl_ros"/>
   <depend package="sensor_msgs"/>
 
 </package>
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35514/where-is-pcl/io/openni_grabber.h-?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-06-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-02**:
Are you trying to use the stand-alone PCL library with ROS? There is still a separate version, packaged as `ros-fuerte-pcl`.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-06-02**:
How to do that? Is there any docs? Thank you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is probably a duplicate of:

- http://answers.ros.org/question/34693/trying-to-compile-perception_pcl-122-for-fuerte/

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-06-02**:
Isn't ROS combine with PCL perfectly?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-02**:
Not perfectly. With Fuerte it does finally refer to PCL using a rosdep, but it's still a special build of PCL, not the stand-alone library.